# Имеет ли смысл все .jpg конвертировать в .png?

Tags: изображения, png, jpeg, обработка-изображений

Начитан про преимущество формата `.png` над`.jpg`. И тем не менее, последний всё ещё широко применяется. Почему так?

Насколько я понимаю, по неизвестным мне техническим причинам фотокамеры не могут сохранять снимки в формат `.png`, но даже если это так, то почему современные фотокамеры не конвертируют отснятые `.jpg` в `.png`, раз последний лучше?

И наконец, имеет ли смысл для своих сайтов и приложений конвертировать все `.jpg` изображения в `.png`?

Comment: Смысла именно конвертировать нет. Потерянное в jpg качество  конвертацией вы не вернёте.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В этих форматов разное предназначение. JPEG отлично подходит для фото, потому что те потери, которые происходят при кодировании, почти незаметные на фото. Все дело в том, что на фото нет очень резких переходов между соседними пикселями, и алгоритм JPEG эксплуатирует это свойство.
PNG имеет сжатие без потерь, его алгоритмы плохо справляются с фотографиями, и отлично работают на искусственно сгенерированных изображениях, будто текст, какие-то графики, диаграммы, или просто скриншот веб страницы на подобии stackoverflow.

Не нужно слепо все конвертировать в PNG. Лучший подход - фото/фотоподобные большие картинки в JPEG, простые или маленькие - в PNG.

Почему камеры используют JPEG. Скорость кодирования в JPEG занимает некоторое время, которое зависит только от размера картинки. С PNG сложнее, потому что для лучшего кодирования алгоритм пробует разные алгоритмы. В камере ограниченные вычислительные ресурсы, и кодирование в JPEG проще реализовать на уровне микропроцессора. Это позволит сделать больше снимков за единицу времени. Во-вторых, фотокамерам нет смысла делать фото в PNG без потерь. Если вы посмотрите на увеличенное фото с любой цифровой камеры (даже сжатое без потерь) вы увидите небольшие помехи на уровне соседних пикселей. Кодирование JPEG еще немного искажает соседние пиксели, но на конечное качество это почти никак не влияет. В-третьих, PNG фото будет занимать в несколько раз больше места и раньше это было проблемой.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за подробное объяснение!

Answer (score 0):

[Берём типичную фотографию отсюда.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lamborghini_Super_Trofeo_99_2010_amk.JPG) Сохраняем. Конвертируем в PNG:

```
convert 500px-Lamborghini.jpg 500px-Lamborghini.png
```

Смотрим на размеры:

```
$ du -sh 500px-Lamborghini.*
32K     500px-Lamborghini.jpg
136K    500px-Lamborghini.png
```

Итого: переход на PNG привёл к увеличению размеров типичной фотографии в четыре раза. Если это ваша цель, то да - переход на PNG имеет смысл. Иначе, не очень. Фото лучше оставить в исходном формате.

Comment: Разные картинки по-разному сжимаются. Сжатие зависит от того что изображено на картинке.